# Svelte (Not sveltekit) css inline is too slow

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

Currently I am setting styles reactively & programatically, because inline css doesn't support :hover, so I am forced to programatically emulate it, which leads to :hover styling sometimes taking up to 5 seconds to take place after the initial mouse hovering. Svelte is pretty limiting, not allowing loops in css, or inline :hover. What are my other options in order to setting :hover styling like below?

```js
let buttonStyles = [];
$: {
  buttonStyles = $buttonColors.map((buttonColor, index) => ({
    btnBorderRadius: $borderRadius[index],
    txtColor: hexToRgba(buttonColor[0].text.color, buttonColor[0].text.alpha),
    btnColor: hexToRgba(buttonColor[0].button.color,
      buttonColor[0].button.alpha),
    btnHover: hexToRgba(buttonColor[0].hover.color, buttonColor[0].hover.alpha),
    btnBorder: hexToRgba(buttonColor[0].border.color, buttonColor[0].border.alpha),
    btnShadow: hexToRgba(buttonColor[0].shadow.color, buttonColor[0].shadow.alpha),
  }));
}
```

```html
<div class="output-body" style="height: 100vh; background-color: {hexToRgba($bodyBackgroundColor.bodybackground.color, $bodyBackgroundColor.bodybackground.alpha)};">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" on:click={navigateToEditor} class="logo-container">
    <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" class="site-logo" />
  </a>
  <br />

  <h1 class="editing-text" style="margin-top: 2rem; background: none;">
    {$editedText}
  </h1>

  {#each $buttonNames as name, index (index)}
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="recipe-link" on:click={()=> openModal(index)}
    on:mouseover={() => hoveredIndex = index}
    on:mouseout={() => hoveredIndex = null}
    on:focus={() => hoveredIndex = index}
    on:blur={() => hoveredIndex = null}
    style="background-color: {hoveredIndex === index ? 
    hexToRgba($buttonColors[index][0].hover.color, $buttonColors[index][0].hover.alpha) : 
    hexToRgba($buttonColors[index][0].button.color, $buttonColors[index][0].button.alpha)};
    border-radius: {$borderRadius[index]}px;
    border-color: {hexToRgba($buttonColors[index][0].border.color, $buttonColors[index][0].border.alpha)};">
    <h2 class="modal-btn-text" style="color: 
      {hexToRgba($buttonColors[index][0].text.color, $buttonColors[index][0].text.alpha)};">{$buttonNames[index]} {$borderRadius[index]}
    </h2>
  </button>
```

Comment: "because inline css doesn't support :hover" that's why you use the `<style>` tag and [classes](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#class-name) instead.

Comment: None of this makes sense to me, why is all your styling data in JS objects in the first place?